# How to send mongodb collection updates in Spark streaming context?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, spark-streaming

How to send the data from a mongodb collection whenever it gets updated to spark streaming context. I have seen [`socketTextStream`](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/scala/streaming/) to write the data to mongodb. But is there any way to read the stream when the collection gets updated? Is there any way to avoid to implement [Custom Receiver](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-custom-receivers.html) for mongodb ? Or If anyone has already implemented, then it will be nice, if someone can share.

Thanking you for any input on this.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is using the CDC pattern where on one side you have the reactive mongo library that can hook onto a collection and receive events like update, insert, delete from the mongodb and on the other side you have a spark streaming application that will listen on this events.

The transport engine of the events can be any publish/subscriber system (e.g Kafka)

Comment: `The transport engine of the events can be any publish/subscriber system (e.g Kafka)` . I think this is more suitable in my case. Thanks